# Latex code for table with multiple coulmn

Tags: tables

[image]

Can anyone please help me with the code generation of this table format. Also may I know how do we assign the table width and alignment to fit the text.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  There's too little information here for us to do anything but guess.  Is this for inclusion in a book, an article, lab notes, or something else?  Will the cells be filled, or is this to be printed out so that something can be written in?  As it is, the best suggestion I can give is to look for existing documentation on `table` with good examples.

Comment: You can construct tables in LaTeX via the `\tabularray` package.

Comment: Have look here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables